# Usage policy on the Facebook Place API

Tags: api, facebook

Do you know if there are requirements or restrictions on Facebook Place API?
Is it possible to download the data? Is it open-source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook Platform Policies state:

> - You will only request the data you need to operate your application.
> - You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any rights to such data.

I see no evidence that any other aspect of the Places API changes this information; this data is not openly licensed or reusable, and it can not be downloaded in bulk in any way.

Comment: (but you should try to keep the data up to date) ok so it's possible to download the data if i update the data !

Comment: The same requirement for Foursquare: Update your database !!